# Multipurpose awk file

Tags: awk

Is it usual to have an awk file containing a number of function used as part of a library, whilst also having code that can actually by run with the awk command on the file itself?

Here is an example

```
function mylib_func() {
 ...
}

function mylib_another_func() {
 ...
}

#-------------------------------------

BEGIN {
  ...
}

$0 ~ end_ere {
   if ( display == 1 ) {
      ## Print denote descriptor
      if ( udscr ) { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print }
      print ""
    }
   display = 0
   next
 }

display { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print }
```

Comment: I would either run it with `awk -f script file` or call the functions from another script.

Comment: quick comment : the `next` is superfluous here, since you already set `display = 0`, so the bottom pattern-action block won't ever match for this row anyway. At the same time, is there code that sets `display = 1` (or it's initiated as `1` ?). cuz if `end_ere` is actually for the end of matches, and you want nothing printed beyond this line , then might as well change that `next` to `exit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

common functions can be collected in a library file and can be included in the desired awk script

```
@include "mylib.awk"
BEGIN{...}
```

or from the command line

```
$ awk -i 'mylib.awk' '...
```

I think it's poor practice to have unused functions/lines in an awk script, also difficult to maintain multiple versions that's spread across multiple files.

Comment: I am not saying I would have unused functions.  If you run the script `firstscript` , the script will use those functions.  But then I could have another script `secondscript` which can call the same functions present in `firstscript`.

Comment: When using some function from another script that's what one has to do, include `@include "mylib.awk"` ?

Comment: Move the common library to its own file and include it in both of your scripts.

Comment: I am tending to agree with you.  Have seen that `@include "mylib.awk"` would not only include the functions but also run any non-function code in that file.